# Splitting a long equation with a curly brace for the equations in two lines

Tags: math-mode, equations, delimiters

The equation that I have pasted below is very long. I want the first equation (e34a) after `dw^2/dx^2` to be split in two lines with a common curly brace for the equation in two lines. My code is

```
\begin{subequations}\label{e34} 
  The Normal Stress are given by 
  \begin{align}
   q = & \overline{C}_1\overline{C}_3\overline{C}_5\dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\big(1+ \alpha^{*}k_s(\frac{w}{q_u})\big)}- \dfrac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\Bigg(G_1 H_1+\overline{C}_2(T_p+T_1)\cos\theta+G_2 H_2\overline{C}_1 \label{e34a}\\
&+ G_3 H_3 \overline{C}_1 \overline{C}_3+G_4 H_4 \overline{C}_1 \overline{C}_3\overline{C}_5+ \overline{C}_1\overline{C}_4(T_p+T_2)\cos\theta+
         \overline{C}_1\overline{C}_3\overline{C}_6(T_p+T_3)\cos\theta\Bigg)\nonumber\\
        \intertext{The Mobilised Tension for top reinforcement is}
            \frac{\partial T_1}{\partial x} = & -\Bigg(q+G_1H_1\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\Bigg)\  \overline{D}_1
            - \Bigg(\overline{C}_3\overline{C}_5\dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\big(1+\alpha^{*}k_s(\frac{w}{q_u})\big)} - A_1 \frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\Bigg)\  \overline{D}_2\\
        \intertext{The Mobilised Tension for middle reinforcement is}
            \frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x} = & -\Bigg(\frac{1}{\overline{C}_1} \Big(q+A_2\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \Big) +G_2 H_2\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \Bigg)\ \overline{D}_3  \label{e34c} \\
            & - \Bigg( \overline{C}_5 \dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\big(1+\alpha^{*}k_s(\frac{w}{q_u})\big)} - A_3 \frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \Bigg)\ \overline{D}_4  \nonumber
            \intertext{The Mobilised Tension for bottom reinforcement is}
            \frac{\partial T_3}{\partial x} = & -\Biggl(\frac{1}{\overline{C}_3}\Bigg(\frac{1}{\overline{C}_1}\Big(q+A_2\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \Big)+A_4\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\Bigg)+G_3 H_3\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \Biggl)\ \overline{D}_5  \label{e34d} \\
            & - \Bigg( \dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\big(1+\alpha^{*}k_s(\frac{w}{q_u})\big)} - G_4H_4 \frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \Bigg)\ \overline{D}_6  \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: Isn't this a continuation of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963414/spliting-a-group-of-long-equations-in-latex ?

Comment: @Reshma if you want to thank someone for having answered your question, upvote his/her answer (if you can) and accept it (if it did answer your question). Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). (This site is not a forum.)

Comment: No its not the same question. But it is a continuation. The equation is longer than that in the previous question. And I want curly braces for the two split equations

Comment: The answer seems the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following code, which uses the `split` environment, defined by the `amsmath` package, to align each of the sub-equatons. Note that I've also attempted to make the code more readable by defining the commands `\Cbar` and `\Dbar`, and by replacing the various `\Bigg` instructions with `\bigg`. (Bigg seems just too big...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Cbar}{\overline{C}}
\newcommand{\Dbar}{\overline{D}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{e34} 
\noindent
The Normal Stress $q$ is given by 
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
q = &\phantom{=} \Cbar_1\Cbar_3\Cbar_5\dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\big(1+ \alpha^{*}k_s 
(w/q_u)\big)}
- \dfrac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg\{G_1 H_1+\Cbar_2(T_p+T_1)\cos\theta 
\label{e34a}\\
&+G_2 H_2\Cbar_1+ G_3 H_3 \Cbar_1 \Cbar_3+G_4 H_4 \Cbar_1 \Cbar_3\Cbar_5\\
&+\Cbar_1\Cbar_4(T_p+T_2)\cos\theta+\Cbar_1\Cbar_3\Cbar_6(T_p+T_3)\cos\theta
\bigg\}\,.\\
\end{split}
\intertext{The Mobilised Tension for top reinforcement is}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial T_1}{\partial x} 
= & -\bigg(q+G_1H_1\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)\  \Dbar_1 \\
&- \bigg(\Cbar_3\Cbar_5\dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\big(1+\alpha^{*}k_s(w/q_u)\big)} 
- A_1 \frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)\  \Dbar_2\\
\end{split}
\intertext{The Mobilised Tension for middle reinforcement is}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x} 
= & -\bigg(\frac{1}{\Cbar_1} 
\Big(q+A_2\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \Big) 
+G_2 H_2\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \bigg)\ \Dbar_3  \label{e34c} \\
&- \bigg( \Cbar_5 \dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\big(1+\alpha^{*}k_s(w/q_u)\big)} 
- A_3 \dfrac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \bigg)\ \Dbar_4\\
\end{split}
\intertext{The Mobilised Tension for bottom reinforcement is}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial T_3}{\partial x} 
= & -\biggl(\frac{1}{\Cbar_3}\bigg(\frac{1}{\Cbar_1}\Big(q+A_2\frac{\partial^{2}w}
{\partial x^{2}} \Big)
+A_4\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)+G_3 H_3\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial
x^{2}} \biggr)\ 
\Dbar_5  \label{e34d} \\
&-\bigg( \dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\big(1+\alpha^{*}k_s(w/q_u)\big)} - G_4H_4 
\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \bigg)\ \Dbar_6 \\
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the use of "`\big` and friends" to be a quick fix that works 99% of the time, with that 1% being quite frustrating to solve. I took [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25096/splitting-a-long-equation-with-a-curly-brace-for-the-equations-in-two-lines/25100#25100) (credit to him for the improved layout of the first two equations) and reverted back to the old trustworthy `\left` and `\right` pairs, where LaTeX decides how to stretch/extend the extensible delimiters `()` and `{}`. There is problem when stretching has to occur across more than one line in an equation though. But for that, `\vphantom{...}` allows a vertical (zero-width) stretch of the correct height. By example, here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Cbar}{\overline{C}}
\newcommand{\Dbar}{\overline{D}}
\newcommand{\myfrac}{\dfrac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}}% For height purposes
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{e34} 
\noindent
The Normal Stress $q$ is given by 
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
q = &\phantom{=} \Cbar_1\Cbar_3\Cbar_5\dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\left(1+ \alpha^{*}k_s 
(w/q_u)\right)}
- \myfrac\left\{\vphantom{\myfrac}G_1 H_1+\Cbar_2(T_p+T_1)\cos\theta \right.
\label{e34a}\\
&+G_2 H_2\Cbar_1+ G_3 H_3 \Cbar_1 \Cbar_3+G_4 H_4 \Cbar_1 \Cbar_3\Cbar_5 \\
&+\>\Cbar_1\Cbar_4(T_p+T_2)\cos\theta+\Cbar_1\Cbar_3\Cbar_6(T_p+T_3)\cos\theta
\left.\vphantom{\myfrac}\!\right\}\,.\\
\end{split}
\intertext{The Mobilised Tension for top reinforcement is}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial T_1}{\partial x} 
= & -\bigg(q+G_1H_1\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)\  \Dbar_1 \\
&- \bigg(\Cbar_3\Cbar_5\dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\big(1+\alpha^{*}k_s(w/q_u)\big)} 
- A_1 \frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\bigg)\  \Dbar_2\\
\end{split}
\intertext{The Mobilised Tension for middle reinforcement is}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x} 
= & -\left(\frac{1}{\Cbar_1} 
\left(q+A_2\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \right) 
+G_2 H_2\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \right)\ \Dbar_3  \label{e34c} \\
&- \left( \Cbar_5 \dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\left(1+\alpha^{*}k_s(w/q_u)\right)} 
- A_3 \dfrac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \right)\ \Dbar_4\\
\end{split}
\intertext{The Mobilised Tension for bottom reinforcement is}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial T_3}{\partial x} 
= & -\left(\frac{1}{\Cbar_3}\left(\frac{1}{\Cbar_1}\left(q+A_2\frac{\partial^{2}w}
{\partial x^{2}} \right)
+A_4\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}\right)+G_3 H_3\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial
x^{2}} \right)\ 
\Dbar_5  \label{e34d} \\
&-\left( \dfrac{\alpha^{*}k_s w}{U\left(1+\alpha^{*}k_s(w/q_u)\right)} - G_4H_4 
\frac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}} \right)\ \Dbar_6 \\
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image: Multiple equations that are split with extensible delimiters]

The macro `\newcommand{\myfrac}{\dfrac{\partial^{2}w}{\partial x^{2}}}` is introduced just for the sake of brevity.

For more ideas on how to work with math in LaTeX, [Herbert Voss' `mathmode` document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) is an invaluable source.

Comment: I like the additional fixes -- automating the sizing of the parentheses, and using a brief macro for the recurring second partial derivative -- you've applied to Reshma's original code. It remains to be seen whether Reshma has anything more to say (including accepting one of the proposed answers)...